# Heroku nil class error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I just pushed my local Rails 4 app to Heroku, and I've got a strange error. As is often the case, it works fine locally with no issues. I think that the Heroku DB / environment is basically the same as the local (as far as I know anyway!)

The error in the Heroku logs is: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass)`

It's trying to tell if an association is `empty` or not-- if it is `empty` display a no results partial-- if it's not `empty` then loop through the results and display a result partial for each.

Controller:

```
@polls     = Poll.where('team_id = ? AND expires_at >= ?', params['id'], DateTime.now())
```

View:

```
<% if @polls.empty? %>
    <%= render partial: "noresults" %>
<% else %>
    <% @polls.each do |p| %>
        <%= render partial: "poll", locals: {poll: p} %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I opened a Heroku console and ran the `@polls` query, which returned a proper association, which I was able to test with `empty?` and it worked as expected.

Any thought what could be causing this?

EDIT:

database.yml

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
```

Comment: Is your app using the heroku config for DATABASE_URL?

Comment: @DavidS-- the "production" config is really simple. I will post above.

Comment: You could just use `.blank?`...

Comment: @Niall-- that appears to have worked-- but I'd be curious to know why? This seems like core rails stuff, not a weird gem dependency or something.

Comment: Just checking boxes here, but are you sure @polls.empty? is what the error is referring to?

Answer (score 0):

**Data**

The issue you've got is you're calling `.empty?` on a variable / data object which hasn't been set

This is a standard issue when you deploy to another environment, as it doesn't have the populated data you have in development. This could either be caused by your `production` db not being populated (no records), or you don't actually have a production db hooked up (unlikely)

To fix this, you'll either want to make sure you have `polls` set, or add another condition to your `if` statement:

```
 <% if !@polls.present? || @polls.empty? %>
     <%= render partial: "noresults" %>
 <% else %>
     ...
 <% end %>
```

---

**Cause**

The bottom line cause is that your variable will not be populated, resulting in your application being unable to call the method you need. This is a standard issue with Rails apps (not just ones running on Heroku)

To resolve it, you basically need to verify the object exists. One way is to use the conditional method I outlined above, or you could use `.blank?` as suggested by `Niall`

Comment: @Rich-- thanks as usual for your great answers-- but as I mentioned in the question, the data is in the DB, and I was able to execute the query from a rails console on heroku, which successfully returned the association as expected.

Comment: Hmmm - so it's still causing issues for you?